# Alexa nodejs accessing url from Amazon Lamdba

Tags: alexa

I've created a simple skill for Alexa based on this example:
https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact/blob/en-US/lambda/custom/index.js

Now, I'd like the script to log something on a different server when *GetNewFactIntent* is called.

This is what I'm trying to do but have an issue with *this* which is not what it should be in the *http.get* callback.

```
    'GetNewFactIntent': function () {
    //var thisisit = this;
    http.get("http://example.com", function(res) {
      //console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
      const factArr = data;
      const factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * factArr.length);
      const randomFact = factArr[factIndex];
      const speechOutput = GET_FACT_MESSAGE + randomFact;

      this.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME, randomFact);
      this.response.speak(speechOutput);
      this.emit(':responseReady');
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      //console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
},
```

What *this* needs to be replaced with in the example above for this to work?

Comment: While IoT related I think you'll get a better response asking this on Stack Overflow